# Why $kerT=Span\{\underline 0\}$ if linear map $T: \mathbb{F}_3[x]\to \mathbb{F}_3[x]$ is defined as $T(p(x))=p(-x)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Why $kerT=Span\{\underline 0\}$ if linear map $T: \mathbb{F}_3[x]\to \mathbb{F}_3[x]$ is defined as $T(p(x))=p(-x)$?

$\mathbb{F}_3[x]$ is a space of polynomials of form $ax^2+bx+c$.

The solution I saw finds $\text{ker}T$ as follows:

first $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c \Rightarrow p(-x)=ax^2-bx+c$

then:
$$
\text{ker}T=\{p(x)|ax^2-bx+c=0\}=\{p(x)|a=0 \land -b=0 \land c=0\}=\{\underline 0\}
$$

My question is why necessarily $a,-b,c$ has to be zero in order to satisfy the equation $ax^2-bx+c=0$? What if $a=2,x^2=4, b=2,x=2, c=-4$ then still the equation holds while $a,b,c \neq 0$.

Comment: The kernel of $T$ are all polynomials of order at most 2 that are mapped to the zero polynomial, i.e. the polynomial $0x^2+0x+0$.

Comment: The polynomial has to be zero for any $x$, not just for some $x$, hence all the coefficients must be zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $p \in ker(T)$ and $q$ defined py $q(x)=p(-x)$, then $q(x)=0$ for all $x$. Hence $p(-x)=0$ for all $x$. Thus $p=\underline 0.$

Comment: What if $T$ was defined as $p(x)=p(2)$? Then $p(2)=4a+2b+c$ and $4a+2b+c=0$. In this case would I have to find the general solution to the equation in order to find $kerT$?

Comment: If $T: \mathbb{F}_3[x]\to \mathbb{F}$ is defined by $Tp=p(2)$ and $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$,  then $p \in ker(T) \iff p(x)=ax^2+bx-4a-2b$.

Comment: But the linear map is $\mathbb F_3[x]\to \mathbb F_3[x]$ not $\mathbb F_3[x]\to \mathbb F$. If it's defined by $T(p(x))=p(2)$ then $kerT=\{0\}$ right?

Answer (score 1):

You don't get to choose $x$. The vector space is a space of functions. Choosing $x$ is changing the function to a constant function. But your function is not constant. The zero in this space is the constant 0 function a function of degree  minus infinity(this degree definition is artificial in a way).

Answer (score 1):

The other answers mix the concept of polynomial with *polynomial function*. These concepts agree for many fields (in particular the usual ones, $\mathbb R$, etc.) but not for all.

What happens in the proof you were given is simply that the zero polynomial is the polynomial with all coefficients equal to zero. In your example, the polynomial $2x^2+2x-4$ is not zero, irrespective that the corresponding polynomial function could be zero for some (and then maybe all, for certain fields) $x$.

Comment: I guess an easier/another way to look at this is to convert the polynomial into vector coordinates. Then for example $T(p(x))=p(2)=8a+4b+2c+d \Rightarrow T(a,b,c,d)=(8a,4b,2c,d)$. So in order to find $kerT$ we just get $8a=0,4b=0,2c=0,d=0\Rightarrow ker(T)=\{0\}$ right?

Comment: Exactly. The $T$ in the question is $(a,b,c)\longmapsto(a,-b,c)$.

Comment: Sorry, now I read your comment better. In the example from your comment, if $Tp=p(2)$, then you are mapping $T$ to a number (and $T$ will always have kernel). But in your question you map polynomials to polynomials.

Comment: So in the example from the comment I'd need to find the general solution to $8a+4b+2c+d=0$ right?

Comment: Yes, the polynomials whose coefficients satisfy that equation will be the kernel of that $T$.